# Как реализовать непрерывное выполнение динамически изменяющегося кол-ва задач на gearman?

Tags: php, laravel, gearman

Доброе время суток!

Есть цепочка задач. Для наглядности опишу.

- Парсер ищет и сравнивает названия(товаров например) на нескольких сайтах(пока 3, но будет больше)
- По списку совпавших названий парсятся страницы с хар-ками товаров
- Затем хар-ки сравниваются и расхождения складываются в бд

В данный момент клиент отправляет задачи воркеру, и функция намеренно зацикливается для постоянной отработки(раз в 5 сек).

Как правильно организовать непрерывное и параллельное(потому что таких цепочек несколько, в зависимости от кол-ва категорий товаров) выполнение данных цепочек?
А так же, товаров может быть много(более 40) и приходится долго ждать ответа от сайта, поэтому их тоже нужно как то разбить(например по 20 шт).

Правильный ли выбор - gearman?
Подскажите, может есть у кого нибудь опыт в это? Если можно несколько нормальных примеров(документации по gearman-у не хватает).

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно, чтобы каждая операция выполняла ровно одно логическое действие.

1. Парсер ищет названия товаров и складывает их в бд.
2. Воркер №1 сравнивает названия и, в зависимости от вашей логики, помечает нужный товар, как готовый к обработке (сделайте поле статус - READY_FOR_ANALYZE, ANALYZE_IN_PROGRESS, ANALYZE_COMPLETE и т.д.).
3. Воркер №2 берет первый (например, по дате добавление) товар, собирает странички, которые нужно спарсить, и так же складывает их в базу.
4. Воркер №3 берет страничку из базы, парсит ее и переходит к следующей.

Если ваша проблема в том, что товаров много, просто запускайте несколько воркеров №2. Если проблема в том, что приходится долго ждать ответа от сайта, запускайте несколько воркеров №3.

И, скорее всего, вам не нужен отдельный сервер очередей (gearman, rabbitmq) для задач с 20-40 объектами для обработки. Двух таблиц в базе данных (items, items_pages) и правильно определенных статусов для записей вам должно хватить. Чем меньше зоопарка в проекте, тем проще проект развивать и поддерживать.

Comment: Вы немного не правы. Сервер очередей позволяет не задумываться о блокировках задач при параллельном их выполнении и повторном возвращении задач в очередь, если воркер внезапно сдох. Уж лучше использовать gearman (rabbitmq, activemq, ...) чем писать собственный велосипед.

Comment: В данном случае надо сравнивать затраты на написание собственного велосипеда и поддержки велосипеда готового. Исходя из заявленных топикстартером условий, использование gearman, rabbitmq или чего-то подобного мне кажется неоправданным.

Comment: Как только у вас появится больше одного воркера -- нужно  будет реализовывать блокировку задач (+ защиту от dead-lock). Поверьте, готовые решения _уже работают_, в отличии от велосипеда, который еще нужно написать и отладить.

Comment: В донном случае gearman используется для распределения нагрузки по 3 виртуальным серверам, т.к. происходит много итераций за короткий промежуток времени(каждая задача запускается раз в 3-5 сек и это необходимо). Вопрос был в том, как сделать динамически запускающиеся и остонавливающиеся воркеры, чтобы не создавалось очереди.

Comment: Как правило воркер, это процесс, постоянно висящий в памяти и ждущий сообщений из сервера очередей. Т.е. вы один раз запустили какое-то количество воркеров, они постоянно висят в памяти и по необходимости отрабатывают. Количество воркеров зависит от ваших потребностей, его всегда можно увеличить, если задачи долго находятся в очереди, или уменьшить, если какие-то воркеры задач не получают.